# How to read (interpret) xmodmap -pke

Tags: x11, key-bindings

I am trying to get `xdotools` to type a backslash on a German keyboard. After a number of attempts, and a lot of `xev` and googling I managed to do it by using

```
xdotool key 108+20
```

and now I am trying to generalize the solution a bit - for example for a tilde, which is:

```
xdotool key 108+35
```

In doing so I read the output of `xmodmap -pke`

```
keycode  20 = ssharp question minus underscore backslash questiondown U1E9E
keycode  35 = plus asterisk bracketright braceright asciitilde macron
keycode  49 = dead_circumflex degree grave asciitilde U2032 U2033
keycode  51 = numbersign apostrophe backslash bar rightsinglequotemark dead_breve
```

where I notice the fifth item is always the one that I get if I press the AltGr key on the right if the keyboard. The first item is the one without mod keys, and the second is the one with caps on.

What are the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmodmap#Keymap_table) columns in order represent:

1. <kbd>Key</kbd>
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd>
3. <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd>
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd>
5. <kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd>
6. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd>

<kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd> is indeed mapped to the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key

<kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> is the legacy way of doing <kbd>ISO_Level3_Shift</kbd> and it is [a bit more primitive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55076/what-is-the-mode-switch-modifier-for) 
In current keyboard layouts <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> is not assigned to any physical key, but you may assign it to one and use it as normal